# Use attributes from one query in the next one inside sp

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I need to return two tables from an sp. And I need the second one to use an attribute from the result of the first one. I can do it this way.

```
select UberId, ... from A where ...;
select * from B where UberId in (select UberId from A where ...);
```

But I'm wondering if I can do it without running the bracketed subquery but instead just using the output of the first query directly. Would it be more performant?

Comment: No, you can't reference a prior result set in a latter. If you want, however, the 2 queries, (the first and the latter) to be the same data, you'll likely want to put that data into a temporary table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a temp table.

```
select UberId, ... 
into #t
from A 
where ...;

select * from #t;

select * from B 
where UberId in (select UberId from #t);
```